# Пример использования Select

Tags: windows, select, winsock, c++

Уже почитал описание select, но общая картина не складывается.

Есть программа, где используется select, наборы файловых дескрипторов, неблокирующие сокеты и т.д. Так вот хотелось бы её понять, но анализ кода все равно не дал ответов, почему именно так и как оно все вместе работает, то есть не дал твердого понимания, а мне это нужно для написания промежуточной программы для взаимодействия с ней, поэтому не хотелось бы на догадках делать.

Может вы могли бы посоветовать какую-то статью или книгу с этими инструментами? Гугл не дал результатов, или я неправильно искал. То есть подойдет даже небольшой пример клиент-сервера с двунаправленным каналом и использованием того, что описал выше, и чтобы было описание кода пошаговое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте http://kpnc.opennet.ru/sock.pdf

Comment: Так там же про синхронные сокеты.

Comment: @perfect, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @xinakapu что вам мешает сделать пару клиентов и серверов и перекрестно отправлять и получать данные?